# Jquery contextmenu event always returns e.which as 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, contextmenu

I am using `contextmenu` which is bound using jquery `on`. And i noticed that `e.which` and `e.button` is always `0`.

Is there any reason for this?

```
$("div").on("contextmenu", function(e){
  if(e.which) //Always 0
    //do something
});
```

**Edit:**  My mistake this happens only in IE8, i missed to specify the browser version.

Comment: What are you expecting it to be? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `oncontextmenu` can be raised by either the rightmouse button or the contextmenu button on your keyboard. Effectively there's only one button raising the event. So `0` is appropriate in this case.

Comment: check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arwunqsj) , it returns `3` for me on `right click`

Comment: @AmitSoni, you're right. Could be that the OP's browser is an older version. Still it can only be raised by one button so checking which button (or buttons simulating the right mouse button) fired it seems redundant to me.

Comment: @AmitSoni This is happening in IE8 only.. See my updated question

Comment: @Madhu IE8 used their own spec back then. Today they return the standardized button id. Question remains, why are you checking this?

Answer (score 1):

You should go with `mousedown` event that also works on `IE8`

```
$("div").on("mousedown", function(e){
    alert(e.which);
    if(e.which == 3){
        //do something
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arwunqsj/1/)**